# java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<201>

Tags: java, spring, junit

Hi I'm trying to implement junit in my controller. But what I get is 201 instead of 200.

Below is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/treat")
public class TreatController {

  private final TreatService treatService;

@Autowired
  public TreatController(TreatService treatService){
    this.treatService = treatService;
  }

@PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<CommonResponse> addNew(
      @RequestBody Treat treat) throws RecordNotFoundException{
    CommonResponse response = new CommonResponse();
    response.setStatus(CommonConstants.OK);
    response.setData(treatService.save(treat));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
}
```

next is my Junit testing:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(TreatController.class)
public class TreatControllerTest {

  private RecordNotFoundException recordException = new RecordNotFoundException("");

  private final String title = "{\"title\" : \"title\"}";

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private TreatService treatService;

@Test
  public void addNew() throws Exception{
    Treatment treatment = new Treatment();

    given(treatmentService.save(
        Mockito.any(Treat.class))).willReturn(treat);
    mockMvc.perform(post("/treats")
    .content(title)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))

    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk());

    Mockito.verify(treatService).save(Mockito.any(Treat.class));
  }
}
```

is there anything that I missed?
By the way, I dont use Json. I just inserted it because it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what you return.

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

`HttpStatus.CREATED` returns **201** and indicates that a resource has been created by the request

How ever in your testcase you are expecting OK(200) `.andExpect(status().isOk());`

According to [HTTP1.1/ specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) Post request should always result in the creation of a resource. So it makes sense to return 201 from there. All your need to do is change your testcase assertion expected value to HTTPStatus.CREATED.

Comment: thank you. is there anything you can suggest on my code design?

Comment: Not much! With newer versions of spring your can simply use @Autowired with fields and avoid writing setters for them.

Comment: "is there anything you can suggest on my code design?" - yes - learn what your code does and why it does it. Phrases like "I dont use Json. I just inserted it because it works" (hint: you do use JSON) strongly imply that your approach is to just copy and paste code you find and hope that it works. This will cause you completely avoidable difficulties, especially as the code you write increases in size and complexity. Spend some time reading the official documentation for the libraries you're using (in this case Spring and Mockito) to properly understand it, and it will pay off hugely.

Comment: In my case it didn't work even when having `HttpStatus.CREATED` properly specified in both the test and controller.  I suspect it to be some undocumented error in Mockito.  I ended up refactoring the controller/tests code to remove all mentions of the `ResponseEntity` wrapper, and decorating the methods with `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)` or `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)` instead which seem to work fine with Mockito